# Some websites not loading -16.04

Tags: networking

I have a problem loading some websites after updating. I am using a Wi-fi connetion and have disabled UFW

I have dns: I ran dig @192.168.0.1 www.difficult.com and got back positive results.

> dig @192.168.0.1 www.difficult.com
>
> ; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> @192.168.0.1 www.difficult.com   ; (1
>   server found)    ;; global options: +cmd   ;; Got answer:   ;;
>   ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 4089   ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 3, ADDITIONAL: 4
>
> ;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:   ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096   ;;
>   QUESTION SECTION:   ;www.difficult.com.       IN  A
>
> ;; ANSWER SECTION:   www.difficult.com.   43200   IN  A   66.117.157.35
>
> ;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
>   difficult.com.        172800  IN  NS  cheese.lanminds.net.
>   difficult.com.        172800  IN  NS  ns3.lmi.net.
>   difficult.com.        172800  IN  NS  ns2.lmi.net.     ;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
>   cheese.lanminds.net.  48783   IN  A   115.125.246.67
>   ns3.lmi.net.      48783   IN  A   66.117.140.96
>   ns2.lmi.net.      48783   IN  A   66.117.151.5
>
> ;; Query time: 121 msec   ;; SERVER: 192.168.0.1#53(192.168.0.1)   ;;
>   WHEN: Sun Jul 17 02:39:08 EDT 2016   ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 183

I have run ifconfig -a and the results look good to me

> wlp6s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 24:ec:99:5b:0c:d2
>             inet addr:192.168.0.182  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
>             inet6 addr: fe80::792e:948c:29e7:f3d2/64 Scope:Link
>             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:93912 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:61358 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
>             RX bytes:111669895 (111.6 MB)  TX bytes:8966689 (8.9 MB)

Results of a site i pinged that I cannot connect to

> ping www.jobbank.gc.ca   PING www.jobbank.gc.ca (167.227.34.131)
>   56(84) bytes of data.   From 192.168.0.182 icmp_seq=1 Destination Port
>   Unreachable   From 192.168.0.182 icmp_seq=2 Destination Port
>   Unreachable   From 192.168.0.182 icmp_seq=3 Destination Port
>   Unreachable   From 192.168.0.182 icmp_seq=4 Destination Port
>   Unreachable   From 192.168.0.182 icmp_seq=5 Destination Port
>   Unreachable   From 192.168.0.182 icmp_seq=6 Destination Port
>   Unreachable   From 192.168.0.182 icmp_seq=7 Destination Port
>   Unreachable   ^C
>   --- www.jobbank.gc.ca ping statistics ---   7 packets transmitted, 0 received, +7 errors, 100% packet loss, time 6006ms

this is a traceroute of the same site i cannot connect to

> sudo traceroute 167.227.34.131 traceroute to 167.227.34.131
>   (167.227.34.131), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets  1  192.168.0.182
>   (192.168.0.182)  0.231 ms  0.405 ms  0.477 ms

dig @127.0.0.1  (had to re-install dnsmasq) *thanks*

> ; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> dig @127.0.0.1
>   ;; global options:
>   +cmd
>   ;; Got answer:
>   ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 57569
>   ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1,
>   ADDITIONAL: 1
>
> ;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION: ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096 ;;
>   QUESTION SECTION: ;dig.               IN  A
>
> ;; AUTHORITY SECTION: .           10800   IN  SOA a.root-servers.net.
>   nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2016071700 1800 900 604800 86400
>
> ;; Query time: 111 msec ;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1) ;; WHEN:
>   Sun Jul 17 12:28:06 EDT 2016 ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 107

sudo netstat -peanut
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          3688388     24742/dnsmasq
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          105524      4237/dnsmasq
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9150          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       258628      9518/tor
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9151          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       258629      9518/tor
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.182:57580     172.217.1.110:80        ESTABLISHED 1000       3699194     24859/opera
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9151          127.0.0.1:58176         ESTABLISHED 1000       259205      9518/tor
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9151          127.0.0.1:58180         ESTABLISHED 1000       259209      9518/tor
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.182:49210     172.217.1.99:443        ESTABLISHED 1000       3699144     24859/opera
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.182:33342     107.167.110.245:443     ESTABLISHED 1000       3699149     24859/opera
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.182:55952     107.167.110.247:443     ESTABLISHED 1000       3698969     24859/opera
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.182:52486     91.203.99.18:443        ESTABLISHED 1000       3705507     24859/opera
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.182:52482     91.203.99.18:443        TIME_WAIT   0          0           -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:58186         127.0.0.1:9151          ESTABLISHED 1000       259621      9489/firefox
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:58176         127.0.0.1:9151          ESTABLISHED 1000       258632      9489/firefox
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.182:51826     185.21.100.50:9001      ESTABLISHED 1000       259204      9518/tor
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.182:52488     91.203.99.18:443        ESTABLISHED 1000       3705511     24859/opera
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9151          127.0.0.1:58186         ESTABLISHED 1000       259622      9518/tor
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.182:51992     172.217.1.99:80         ESTABLISHED 1000       3698971     24859/opera
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:58180         127.0.0.1:9151          ESTABLISHED 1000       258655      9489/firefox
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           111        17602       829/avahi-daemon: r
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:43665           0.0.0.0:*                           111        17604       829/avahi-daemon: r
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           0          3688387     24742/dnsmasq
udp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           0          105523      4237/dnsmasq
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           0          250152      9105/dhclient
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4500            0.0.0.0:*                           0          18385       1116/iked
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:500             0.0.0.0:*                           0          18384       1116/iked
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*                           0          18597       960/cups-browsed
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                111        17603       829/avahi-daemon: r
udp6       0      0 :::48810                :::*                                111        17605

Any site I can connect to is a normal ping and traceroute response and
I can use Tor Browser normally and get to any site

I can use my cell phone with the same connection and have no problems at all!

Can anyone shed some light on this situation?

Comment: Are you running any proxy between your computer and the internet? If you do you may want to disable that and try loading pages again.

Comment: Please try to `dig @127.0.0.1` to make sure dnsmasq is working properly, too.

Comment: I am not using a proxy

Comment: Reposted from an answer by Dan who asked this question: *Close thread. I did a fresh install as the situation worsened.*